# Bootstrap carousel active image click action not tiggered

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a bootstrap carousel. If I click the image in the carousel then the following click event is triggered.

If I navigate to next slide by next arrow then the click function not triggered.

```js
$('#inn_carousel-inner .active').find('img').on('click',function(e) {
  console.log('triggered');

  var offset = $(this).offset();
  var x = (e.pageX - offset.left);
  var y = (e.pageY - offset.top);

  console.log('X: '+x);
  console.log('Y: '+y);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="carousel-inner" id="inn_carousel-inner">

  <div class="carousel-item active" data-ftype="Image" data-slideid="1">
    <img src="img0.png" alt="Content" class="img0">
  </div>

  <div class="carousel-item" data-ftype="Image" data-slideid="2">
    <img alt="Content" class="img1" src="img2.png">
  </div>

  <div class="carousel-item " data-ftype="Image" data-slideid="3">
    <img data-src="img3.png" alt="Content" class="img2">
  </div>

  <div class="carousel-item " data-ftype="Image" data-slideid="4">
    <img data-src="img4.png" alt="Content" class="img3">
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's important that just the active element triggers the click handler, you have to set the event listener again after changing the class `#active` (and deactivate the old listener before changing that class). Therefor you should define the listener in a function that you can call when you change the class.

**Working example**:

```js
$('#next').on('click', function() {
    $('#inn_carousel-inner .active img').off('click');
    $('#inn_carousel-inner .active').first().removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
    
    setClick();
});
function setClick() {
    $('#inn_carousel-inner .active img').on('click',function(e) {
      console.log('triggered');

      var offset = $(this).offset();
      var x = (e.pageX - offset.left);
      var y = (e.pageY - offset.top);

      console.log('X: '+x);
      console.log('Y: '+y);
    });
}

setClick();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="carousel-inner" id="inn_carousel-inner">

  <div class="carousel-item active" data-ftype="Image" data-slideid="1">
    <img src="img0.png" alt="Content" class="img0">
  </div>

  <div class="carousel-item" data-ftype="Image" data-slideid="2">
    <img alt="Content" class="img1" src="img2.png">
  </div>

  <div class="carousel-item " data-ftype="Image" data-slideid="3">
    <img data-src="img3.png" alt="Content" class="img2">
  </div>

  <div class="carousel-item " data-ftype="Image" data-slideid="4">
    <img data-src="img4.png" alt="Content" class="img3">
  </div>

</div>

<button id="next">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are attaching the listener to just the first image when it has the class active at that time.

If you change your selector from `$('#inn_carousel-inner .active')` to just `$('#inn_carousel-inner')` then it should work.